# What lay out to use to mimic this pdf format in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, layout

I am trying to recreate this precisely in LaTeX but nothing I try works (tried table, \qaud and even pasting as figure - which does the job but brings other difficulties). Anyone have a simple tip?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You might be interested in the `tabularx` package. Your chance of getting help will increase if you post what you have tried so far, such that we don't have to type the text ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `enumerate` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{labelwidth=15pt, align=left}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[E]  Bla bla
    \item[M]  Jadda jadda
    \item[I]  Lalala la
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @DG', I tried this but without the [E]. Thanks alot!